# A few questions about CloudKits

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I don't know it's the right place to ask these questions or not. But I think it's still related to programming. My questions are:

1. How can I delete the Application in CloudKit Dashboard ?
2. How can I backup my data ? Or in another word, is it possible to download data from my server? ( The reason is I may still not very sure if CloudKit is my final decision. I may shift to another solution for example, parse.com, in the future because of its ability of cross platform.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Sorry, you can't (at the moment, You can only clear all data (select container, goto deployment, klick on Reset development environment.
2. You could create an OSX app that accesses the same container. That app can query al data and store  it wherever you like

Comment: Can I still create an OSX app to accesses the same container if only having iOS Developer Program, no Mac Developer Program?

Comment: I think you also need an OSX Developer Program because you need to sign the app.